# How do I create a canonical transformation matrix from one given with respect to bases?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

It sounded simple at first, but I cant manage to find a proper solution...

So I have as exercise:

> The linear mapping T returns for T(2,1) the vector (0,0) and for T(-1,1) the vector (1,0).
> Give the canonical basis of T!

So I guess the change of coordinates matrix from the given basis to the canonical ones is
\begin{bmatrix}2&-1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}

Now usually, I computed the matrix from the canonical basis to a given basis where the formula was always the inverted change of basis matrix times the transformation matrix times the change of basis matrix. Do I have to switch the matrixes here since I am going from a matrix with base x to the canonical one?

Any help would be much appreciated

PS: I think I am getting closer to the concept of applying a change of basis to a linear transformation, but I am still confused.

For example when I have a transformation that maps from a certain basis b in the domain, to the canonical basis in the codomain, how do I get the function going from the canonical basis to the canonical basis?

Do I multiply by the identity matrix from basis to canonical or from canonical to basis?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Is $T$ a linear map?

Comment: thanks and yes!

Comment: Do you know what the canonical basis of a linear transformation is?  See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_basis#Linear_algebra

Comment: i thought so, like the most basic bases with respect to a certain dimension? I dont know what a jordan chain is as in the article though...